# How to keep lable choosed on select option after refresh page

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, select

I wand keep lable choosed on select option after refresh page. Please help me !

Ex : I choosed "Architekten"

My select dropdown

[image]

I want after refresh page, it keep "Architekten" like this

[image]

My select code

```
<select name="branche" id="branche">
<option id="select" value="select" disabled="" selected="">Please Select</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="49">Alternativ &amp; Ganzheitliche Medizin</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="50">Ambulatorien</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="51">Apotheken</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="52">Architekten</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="53">Ärzte</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="54">Astrologen</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="55">Baumärkte</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="56">Beisel &amp; Kneipen</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="57">Bestatter</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="58">Bijouteriewaren</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select" value="59">Blumenhandel &amp; Floristik</option>
</select>
```

My jquery

```
<script>
document.getElementById('branche').onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedtem', document.getElementById('branche').value);
};

if (localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')) {
    document.getElementById('branche').options[localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')].selected = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, one DOM can not suppose to have one id attribute more that one, so please update that or I have another quick solution for you,

```
<select name="branche" id="branche">
<option id="select" value="select" disabled="" selected="">Please Select</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_49" value="49">Alternativ &amp; Ganzheitliche Medizin</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_50" value="50">Ambulatorien</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_51" value="51">Apotheken</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_52" value="52">Architekten</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_53" value="53">Ärzte</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_54" value="54">Astrologen</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_55" value="55">Baumärkte</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_56" value="56">Beisel &amp; Kneipen</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_57" value="57">Bestatter</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_58" value="58">Bijouteriewaren</option>
<option id="wk_sl_search_select_59" value="59">Blumenhandel &amp; Floristik</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementById('branche').onchange = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedtem', document.getElementById('branche').value);
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')) {
        document.getElementById('wk_sl_search_select_'+localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')).selected = true;
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: hi Ankit Srivastava. It work but turn it off and turn it on again, It is still selected, not Please Select

Comment: for this, you can modify the codes of the second if condition, and add a check that if value == 'select' then select the option with ID select.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this script with your existing Script code:

```
<script>
 $('#branche').change(function(event){
        var selectedcategory = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        sessionStorage.setItem("itemName",selectedcategory);
});

$('select').find('option[value='+sessionStorage.getItem('itemName')+']').attr('selected','selected');

 </script>
```